# Bigquery - Illegal non-space trailing data '1' in string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am running below query in bigquery . Data type of TS_Estimated_Dispatch  is string.

```
            SELECT
            Order_Number
            FROM
            `MYTABLE`
            WHERE
            Customer_Country = 'ABC'
            AND Partner_Country = 'DEF'
            AND SO_Item_Status IN (1,2,3)
            AND TIMESTAMP(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',
            TS_Estimated_Dispatch )) > '2018-04-20'
```

Errors : Query Failed
Error: Illegal non-space trailing data '1' in string "2018-04-22 17:00:00"

Comment: My guess is that you have data in `TS_Estimated_Dispatch` which can't be parsed using that format mask.  You left out this data, but you should include it.

Comment: Try `substr(TS_Estimated_Dispatch, 1, 10)` in the last expression.

Comment: substr(TS_Estimated_Dispatch, 1, 10) is not working , getting 0 rows .

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you actually want to do. You already have a comparable date format in this string: `2018-04-22 17:00:00` so it's enough if you use that in compare

```
select '2018-04-22 17:00:00'>'2018-04-21';
select TS_Estimated_Dispatch > '2018-04-20';
```

On the other hand parsing a string, always needs to be on exact length, so if you have 10 chars used in the pattern %Y-%m-%d you need to use on a string that has similar length.

```
select PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', substr('2008-12-25 22:30:00',1,10))
select PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', substr(TS_Estimated_Dispatch ,1,10)) > DATE('2008-12-23')
```

this returns `DATE` so in order to compare, you need to compare with a DATE field and not an arbitrary written string.